# Customizar Session gerada pelo spring

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

Possuo o seguinte cenário:

- uma aplicação nodejs que salva a sessão no redis.
- outra aplicação spring q também salva a sessão no redis.

Gostaria de compartilhar essa mesma sessão entre as duas aplicações.
Pensei na seguinte forma de fazer isso (não sei se está correta), reescrever o filtro http modificando a forma como ele monta a sessão, encontrei duas classes que acho que deveria reescrever: SessionRepositoryFilter e RedisOperationsSessionRepository.

Será que estou no caminho certo, ou teria uma forma mais simples que resolver meu problema?

Comment: São aplicações distintas em ambientes distintos e você deseja compartilhar a mesma sessão? Não pude entender muito bem a sua dúvida... mas caso seja como eu entendi, creio que não seja possível (por questões de segurança e outras mais) esse tipo de compartilhamento.

Comment: Bom, o cenário que tenho é um pouco mais complexo, possuo um servidor nginx que quando entro no endereço meu-server.com/app-node ele faz um balanceamento de carga entre vários nós onde minha aplicação está rodando, o mesmo nginx quando acesso o caminho meu-server.com/app-spring faz o mesmo serviço, o que acontece é que quando o usuário acessar /app-node pede login e quando ele vai para /app-spring ele pede login novamente. Mudando um pouco a descrição, gostaria de fazer um SingleSignOn entre elas.

Comment: Realmente o que você precisa é de Single Sign On (SSO), mas isto não significa compartilhar sessão, pois cada aplicação identifica usuários de forma diferente. Você precisa configurar uma terceira aplicação para funcionar como servidor de autenticação e as outras duas já existentes irão confiar nesta terceira para fazer isto. Não recomendo você criar sua própria solução, mas usar alguma ferramenta conhecida na área. Eu já tive contato com algumas ferramentas como JOSSO, mas sinceramente não sei qual o estado da arte hoje, ainda mais se considerar soluções em outras tecnologias.

Comment: muito obrigado @utluiz foi exatamente nessa conclusão que acabei chegando aqui com minha equipe.

Comment: @arkanjoms Se puder resumir a decisão da sua equipe numa resposta aqui seria excelente para ajudar futuras pessoas que tivessem a mesma dúvida. Se não puder eu posso transformar meu comentário numa resposta.

Comment: boa idéia @utluiz vou editar minha pergunta adicionando a solução encontrada.

Comment: Você pode responder à sua própria pergunta, fica melhor.

Answer (score 0):

**Solução**

Montamos o ambiente da seguinte forma:

1. nginx como load balancer e proxy-reverso, ele intercepta qualquer requisição e redireciona pra url /auth, onde existe uma aplicação só pra autenticação que retorna 200 caso o usuário esteja autenticado e faz o redirect pra url original, caso não esteja autenticado ele retorna o erro 401 e o nginx redireciona pra página de login;
2. aplicação node e spring só aceita requisições do nginx pra não deixar acesso não autorizado.

Por enquanto não tivemos maiores problemas trabalhando dessa forma, mas ainda estamos validando e vendo alternativas.